# Verificando se existe dados dentro de uma lista de listas

Tags: python, lista

Tenho uma lista de listas. Assim:

```
lista = [['2746', '8512.20.21', '2 - Estrangeira - Adquirida no mercado interno, exceto a indicada no código 7', 'SL-121410', '6949999876781'],['2747', '8512.20.21', '2 - Estrangeira - Adquirida no mercado interno, exceto a indicada no código 7', 'SL-121410CR', '6949999876798'],['2794', '8512.20.21', '2 - Estrangeira - Adquirida no mercado interno, exceto a indicada no código 7', 'SL-121510', '6949999876811']]
```

E eu gostaria de verificar se existe uma string dentro dessa lista. Tentei usar o `in`, mas não obtive o resultado.

```
EAN = "6949999876811"
    
if EAN in lista:
        print(f'EAN {EAN} encontrado')

    else:
        print(f'EAN {EAN} não encontrado')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem uma lista de listas (cada elemento de `lista` é **outra** lista):

```
lista = [
  # primeiro elemento de "lista"
  ['2746', '8512.20.21', '2 - Estrangeira - Adquirida no mercado interno, exceto a indicada no código 7', 'SL-121410', '6949999876781'],
  # segundo elemento de "lista"
  ['2747', '8512.20.21', '2 - Estrangeira - Adquirida no mercado interno, exceto a indicada no código 7', 'SL-121410CR', '6949999876798'],
  # terceiro elemento de "lista"
  ['2794', '8512.20.21', '2 - Estrangeira - Adquirida no mercado interno, exceto a indicada no código 7', 'SL-121510', '6949999876811']
]
```

Quando você faz `EAN in lista`, o valor de `EAN` é comparado com essas sublistas, e não com os valores dentro delas).

Sendo assim, você deve percorrer estas sublistas e verificar se o valor está dentro delas:

```
EAN = "6949999876811"

for sublista in lista: # para cada sublista
    if EAN in sublista: # verifica se está na sublista
        print(f'EAN {EAN} encontrado')
        break # encontrei, pode interromper o for
else: # não encontrou nenhum
    print(f'EAN {EAN} não encontrado')
```

Se `EAN` for encontrado, eu uso `break` para interromper o `for`, pois se já encontrei, entendi que não precisa continuar procurando.

Caso não encontre nenhum (ou seja, caso o `break` não seja chamado), ele cai no `else` (repare que este `else` é do `for` e não do `if` - [em Python isso é perfeitamente normal](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)) e imprime a respectiva mensagem.

---

Se quiser, também pode tratar todas as sublistas como um único iterável, assim é possível verificar a existência de `EAN` direatamente. Para isso, basta usar o [módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import chain

if EAN in chain.from_iterable(lista):
    print(f'EAN {EAN} encontrado')
else:
    print(f'EAN {EAN} não encontrado')
```

[`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) faz com que todas as sublistas de `lista` sejam tratadas como um único iterável, assim você pode verificar se `EAN` existe diretamente nela.

---

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/475252/112052) (que foi apagada) também funciona, mas o detalhe é que a [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) usada lá (`[item for sublista in lista for item in sublista]`) acaba criando **outra** lista contendo todos os elementos. É claro que para poucos elementos - como é o caso - não faz tanta diferença assim, mas eu não criaria outra lista só para procurar um elemento, sendo que é possível fazê-lo sem criar nenhuma outra estrutura adicional (no caso do `chain.from_iterable`, ele cria um iterável, que itera pelos elementos e em seguida os descarta, portanto não há a criação de outra lista).

Isso pode ser corrigido trocando os colchetes por parênteses (pois assim ela se torna uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), que também computa os elementos um por vez, em vez de criar outra lista). Mas aí você pode usar em conjunto com [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), para verificar se há algum elemento que satisfaz a condição:

```
# se tem algum elemento que é igual a EAN
if any(item for item in sublista for sublista in lista if EAN == item):
    print(f'EAN {EAN} encontrado')
else:
    print(f'EAN {EAN} não encontrado')
```

Comment: Verdade! Boa! Abraço!